# UWP link to serial port

Tags: uwp

I want to  create an UWP application to receive information sent by Waspmote board.

in WindowsForms, it's `using System.IO.Ports;` it can work

but in UWP, it show me this error:
[image]

how can I solve this problem, and be able to receive the message from serial port

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to use an old API which is not accessible to UWP apps.

Serial communication can be achieved by using the classes from [Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication).

The class you'll use is [SerialDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice) which will allow you to enumerate, open the device and perform I/O operations.

In order to use the API, you will need to add the *serial port* capability in your application manifest. UWP applications can only access to declared hardware resources.

```
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="vidpid:045E 0610">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort"/>
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

or if you want to access any hardware:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort"/>
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

You will find a full [serial port sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess) as part of the UWP sample collection.

Comment: I still confused, I ask the question more in detail again, can you help me solve it? thank you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798265/uwp-serial-devices)