# Uwp serial devices

Tags: uwp, serial-port

I'm creating a UWP APP to receive the data from waspmote board,  I was used WindForm to develop it, it can work, but because UWP doesn't support `using System.IO.Port` so I use `using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;` I look through the papers, but I still have no idea how can I start, how can I convert the windform code to UWP code?

the windform code as below

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getAvailablePorts();
    }
    void getAvailablePorts()
    {
        // Get a list of existing ports
        String[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        String[] baudrates = new String[] { "9600", "115200" };
        // Insert the lists into the combo boxes
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports);
        comboBox2.Items.AddRange(baudrates);
        // Select the default setting if at least a com port is found.
        if (ports.Count() != 0)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (comboBox1.Text == "" || comboBox2.Text == "")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Please select port settings";
            }
            else
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
                serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);
                serialPort1.DataReceived += new
                SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
                serialPort1.Open();
                progressBar1.Value = 100;
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "UnauthorizedAccess";
        }
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,
    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string value = sp.ReadExisting();
        processValue(value);
    }
    //Delegate to update received data in the textbox
    private delegate void processValueDelegate(string value);
    private void processValue(string value)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new processValueDelegate(processValue),
            new object[] { value });
        }
        else
        {
            // ... update GUI in here ...
            textBox1.AppendText(value);
            DataExtraction(value);
        }
    }
    string UnreadBuffer = "";
    private void DataExtraction(string RxString)
    {
        UnreadBuffer += RxString;
        // Search for Data Header "<=>"
        int start = UnreadBuffer.IndexOf("<=>");
        int delimiter = UnreadBuffer.IndexOf("#");
        if (start >= 0)
        {
            string row = UnreadBuffer.Substring(start);
            if (delimiter >= 0)
            {
                string[] ExtractedDataFields = row.Split('#');
                if (ExtractedDataFields.Length >= 7)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now);
                    textBox3.Text = ExtractedDataFields[1];
                    textBox4.Text = ExtractedDataFields[2];
                    textBox5.Text = ExtractedDataFields[3];
                    textBox6.Text = ExtractedDataFields[5];
                    UnreadBuffer = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

***And I have anohther question: Since UWP doesn't have serialport in Toolbox, what's  the substitute in UWP?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP link to serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791149/uwp-link-to-serial-port)

Comment: I think @Vincent has answered this question on your previous thread. In UWP, you would need to use [Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication) relevant APIs to achieve it. He also has mentioned the official code sample [Custom serial device sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess). This sample's scenarios actually have told you how to communicate with the Serial device(including read and write data).

Comment: Yes, you'll find everything in the sample. I can write the exact same code here but that would be useless. You should download the sample and try to run scenario 4 (read/write) and start to tweak it for your need. In UWP, you will not have a `SerialPort` control that you can drop and that will handle everything for you. You will have to enumerate the devices first, configure and open the one you want and then retrieve the input/output streams to read and write the data.